# View binary websocket payload in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, binary

I can see WHAT websocket packets are sent, but not what they contain if they are binary.

[image: This one]

Is there any way I can use Chrome to see what the contents of these packets are?

Comment: what do you expect to see? 0s and 1s?

Comment: no, 0 through 255. Also in ascii. It's not too much to ask for, and it would be very useful. Visual studio does it with char arrays.